# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined When trying to map multiple arrays

Tags: reactjs, array.prototype.map

I am trying to map multiple arrays at the same time and im not sure if this is how you do it. I am getting the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

When trying the following code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';
import NavBar from '../header-footer/nav-bar'
import Featured from './FeaturedMealplan'
import RecipeItem from './RecipeItem'

export default class MealPlanDetail extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
          currentId: this.props.match.params.slug,
          mealplanItem: {}, // Full mealplan
          mealplanRecipes: [], // Contains recipe names and difficulty.
      }
  }

  getMealplanItem() {
    Axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/get-mealplan/${this.state.currentId}`
    ).then(response => {
        console.log("response", response)
        this.setState({
            mealplanItem: response.data.mealplan,
            mealplanRecipes: this.state.mealplanRecipes.concat(response.data.mealplan["recipes"]),
            mealplanIngredients: this.state.mealplanIngredients.concat(response.data.mealplan["recipe_info"]),
            recipeItem: response.data.mealplan.recipes
        })
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("mealplan-detail GET Error ", error)
    })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      this.getMealplanItem();
  }

  render() {
      const renderRecipe = this.state.recipes.map((recipe, idx) => {
          return (
              <div key={idx}>
                  <h1>{recipe.recipe_name}</h1>
                  <h2>Recipe Difficulty: <span>{recipe.recipe_dificulty}</span></h2>
                  <div>
                    <RecipeItem recipeItem={this.state.recipeItem} />
                  </div>
              </div>
          )
      })
      return (
          <div>
              <NavBar/>
              <Featured/>
              {renderRecipe}
          </div>
      )
  }
}
```

Data that is given: https://pastebin.com/uYUuRY6U

I just need to be able to format it correctly which this is how I would like it formatted in the renderRecipe return. I am new to mapping and do not know if there is a way to fix or a better way.

Comment: There is never a `this.state.recipes` defined. Not even after the mounting data fetch. What is that supposed to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues in the code that we can improve on:

1. `this.state.recipes` seems to be undefined in your logic. Is it a typo?
2. I would suggest implementing `renderRecipe` as a function instead of a variable.
3. You would only hope to render `renderRecipe` when there is data, but when your component is being mounted, `this.state.recipes` is undefined. It would only have value when `getMealplanItem` gets a response and being defined in the callback. So you should check whether the value is defined before rendering.

Please refer to my comments in the code below.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import NavBar from "../header-footer/nav-bar";
import Featured from "./FeaturedMealplan";
import RecipeItem from "./RecipeItem";

export default class MealPlanDetail extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      // ... define `recipes` if that's what you want
    };
  }

  getMealplanItem() {
    Axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/get-mealplan/${this.state.currentId}`)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("response", response);
        // ... set state `recipes` here if that's what you want
        this.setState({
          mealplanItem: response.data.mealplan,
          mealplanRecipes: this.state.mealplanRecipes.concat(
            response.data.mealplan["recipes"]
          ),
          mealplanIngredients: this.state.mealplanIngredients.concat(
            response.data.mealplan["recipe_info"]
          ),
          recipeItem: response.data.mealplan.recipes
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("mealplan-detail GET Error ", error);
      });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getMealplanItem();
  }

  render() {
    const renderRecipe = () => {
      // change renderRecipe from a variable to a function
      if (!this.state?.recipes) {
        // check whether `recipes` is a defined value
        return null;
      }
      return this.state.recipes.map((recipe, idx) => {
        return (
          <div key={idx}>
            <h1>{recipe.recipe_name}</h1>
            <h2>
              Recipe Difficulty: <span>{recipe.recipe_dificulty}</span>
            </h2>
            <div>
              <RecipeItem recipeItem={this.state.recipeItem} />
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      });
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <NavBar />
        <Featured />
        {renderRecipe()}  // it's a function call now
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is never a `this.state.recipes` defined. Based on data type and comment

```
this.state = {
  currentId: this.props.match.params.slug,
  mealplanItem: {}, // Full mealplan
  mealplanRecipes: [], // Contains recipe names and difficulty.
}
```

I will assume you meant for it to really be `this.state.mealplanRecipes`.

Your render then becomes

```
const renderRecipe = this.state.mealplanRecipes.map((recipe, idx) => {...
```

This can easily handle the initial render with an empty array.